# Why is it not available in CentOS wx.html2 . WebView control？

Tags: python, webview, wxpython, centos8, wx.html2

I use wxpthon library to write UI program in CentOS system wx.html2 . WebView control, the following error is prompted:

```
  File "main.py", line 143, in <module>
    frame = DemoFrame()
  File "main.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._mainPanel = MainPanel( self )
  File "main.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.view = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
NotImplementedError
```

Part of my code is like this:

```
class MainPanel( sp.ScrolledPanel ):
    #Main Panel
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        sp.ScrolledPanel.__init__( self, parent=parent )
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.view = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        self.view.LoadURL( "http://www.baidu.com" )
```

CentOS version：**CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)**

Python version: **Python 3.6.8**

wxPython version: **4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5**

Comment: Are you sure you are importing it separately? i.e. `import wx.html2`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.I have been writing the mswin platform similar applications, I query the relevant information, the default, centos system installed the Firefox browser, Firefox browser based on Gecko kernel code, and wxPython web site seems did not mention the wx. Html2. WebView support for the kernel, so I may need to compile WebKitGTK + by myself, in order to meet the module of its kernel calls, of course this is only for my guess, has not been verified.

Answer (score 2):

`NotImplementedError` means that wxPython was compiled without `wx.html2` support.  The most likely cause of this on Linux is that the WebKit development packages were not present when you installed/compiled wxPython.  To resolve this, install the WebKit2 development package and reinstall wxPython.  On CentOS 8, the WebKit2 development package is `webkit2gtk3-devel`, so install it with the package manager, e.g., `yum install webkit2gtk3-devel` and then uninstall/reinstall wxPython.  Note: you may have to also clear the pip cache so that it won't re-use the previously compiled version of wxPython.